# access a software installed in the superuser to other users

Tags: user, privileges

I have a software/program installed in the root/super user section of the OS. I require that all the users should be able to access that program, without me altering their privileges. How can it be done ?

Comment: If you would mention the OS and the program name as well, answering your question would be much easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by creating soft links/symbolic links.

The program is installed in root user,who has all privileges ; while the other users have few privileges. Hence a soft link should be created in the bin folder to the place where the program is installed. The environment variable for the root user should be set. The referencing required for other users would be done by the environment variable set while creating soft link.

Further reading and steps can be done here :
https://blog.bartbania.com/raspberry_pi/create-symbolic-links-in-linux/